# Retriving stored data in realm Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a todo application which I am using realm to store data. i have writen the database codes for writing to the database and retrive. I have also worked on this particular project before in as a single page code but now I want to improve it by using the MVC approach. this is my  codes.

```
//MARK:- Create Category
func createCategory(name: String, color: String, isCompleted: Bool) -> Void {

    category.name = name
    category.color = color
    category.isCompleted = false
    DBManager.instance.addData(object: category)
}


//MARK:- Read Category
func readCategory(completion: @escaping CompletionHandler) -> Void {

    DBManager.instance.getDataFromDB().forEach({ (category) in
                let category = CategoryModel()
                Data.categoryModels.append(category)
            })

}
```

**Database model**

```
private init() {
        database = try! Realm()
    }

    func getDataFromDB() -> Results<CategoryModel> {
        let categoryArray: Results<CategoryModel> = database.objects(CategoryModel.self)
        return categoryArray
    }


    func addData(object: CategoryModel)   {
        try! database.write {
            database.add(object, update: true)
            print("Added new object")
        }
    }
```

**TodoList Cell**

```
func setup(categoryModel: CategoryModel) -> Void {
        categoryNameLabel.text = categoryModel.name

    }
```

**Todo tableviewcontroller**
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

```
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.CATEGORY_CELL) as! CategoryCell

        cell.setup(categoryModel: Data.categoryModels[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }
```

I am able to add to the database as I can print after adding to the database but I am confused as to how to retrieve the added data.

**Without MVC categorylist.swift**

```
let realm = try! Realm()

var categoryArray : Results<Category>?
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        //nil coalising operator
        return Data.categoryModels.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        //tapping into the super class
        let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)

        if let category = categoryArray?[indexPath.row] {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "#\(category.name)"
            guard let categoryColor = UIColor(hexString: category.color) else {fatalError()}
            cell.backgroundColor = categoryColor
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = ContrastColorOf(categoryColor, returnFlat: true)
        }

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Does this work **getDataFromDB** ??

Comment: yes it does but if there is a better way to factor the code from database I would adapt it

Comment: I added what it looks like without MVC @Sh_Khan

Comment: I have tried something and it returns the number of cells equalling the total number of items in the database but it does not return the categoryName or color

Comment: I updated with codes that returns the number of items in the database but does not return the name and color of the database items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you create a singleton here

```
DBManager.instance
```

you can use it like this inside `numberOfRowsInSection`

```
return  DBManager.instance.getDataFromDB().count
```

and inside `cellForRowAt`

```
let item = DBManager.instance.getDataFromDB()[indexPath.row]
```

but this will keep reading the data every execute , so it's better to remove only

```
let realm = try! Realm()
```

when refactor to **MVC** , and use this inside `viewDidLoad`

```
categoryArray = DBManager.instance.getDataFromDB()
```

and leave the other parts unchanged , note: here i assume that **Category** = **CategoryModel**

Comment: let e update my code with what it looks like not that returns the number of cells

Comment: I updated with codes that returns the number of items in the database but does not return the name and color of the database items

Comment: you don't have to create another dataSource this **Data.categoryModels** you already have it , as this will be a duplicate , directly use your singleton as i explained in answer , as here **Realm()** plays the role of the **M** in **MVC** so no need to make another bridge

Comment: Oh yeah. Got it Thanks

Comment: hi @Sh_Khan could you help check this? still on same topic  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52019746/callback-function-not-reloading-database