# Crashing on writing to realm database

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a todo application which I am using realm to store data. i have written the database codes for writing to the database and retrieve.

When I input into the database for the first time, everything works well that is the data gets inputted into the database but when I try to input another object into the databse,

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Attempting to modify object outside of a write transaction - call beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first.'

```
func createCategory(name: String, color: String, isCompleted: Bool) -> Void {
    category.name = name
    category.color = color
    category.isCompleted = false
    DBManager.instance.addData(object: category)
}
```

**DBManager**

```
func addData(object: CategoryModel)   {
    try! database.write {
        database.add(object, update: true)
        print("Added new object")
    }
}
```

**Add category IBaction**

```
CategoryFunctions.instance.createCategory(name: name, color: color, isCompleted: false)
```

Comment: Maybe fix this first `category.isCompleted = isCompleted` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
.createCategory(name: name, color: color, isCompleted: false)
```

changes the properties of already added object and try to write it again , you need to create a new object , may be you need something like

```
func createCategory(name: String, color: String, isCompleted: Bool) -> Void {
        let category = Category()
        category.name = name
        category.color = color
        category.isCompleted = isCompleted
        DBManager.instance.addData(object: category)

        // or
        let category = Category(name:name,color:color,isCompleted:isCompleted)
        DBManager.instance.addData(object: category)

    }
```

Comment: Thanks it fixed it.

Comment: I have a similar question and if you could help check it out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52017908/retriving-stored-data-in-realm-swift  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Create a new category :

```
func createCategory(name: String, color: String, isCompleted: Bool) {
    let newCategory = Category(name: name, color: color, isCompleted: isCompleted)
    DBManager.instance.addData(object: newCategory)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful too

Comment: Kindly help check this question similarly too  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52017908/retriving-stored-data-in-realm-swift